# Collapse list group in django using dynamic id

Tags: html, django

I am trying to use a dynamic id for bootstrap collapse. The collapse is working, but it doesn't work as expected. There are more than items inside each headings, but only one item is shown when I click on the heading. Here is my index.html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              {% for subject in subjects %}
                 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                 <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#c{{forloop.counter}}" 
                           aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="c{{ forloop.counter}}">
                    {{ subject }}</a></h4>
                 </div>
              {% for practical in practicals %}
                {% if practical.subject == subject %}
                <div id="c{{forloop.counter}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel"">
                  <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="{% url 'practicals:detail' practical.id %}">{{ practical }}</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                 {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have included the link to the js

My model.py is:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    subName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subName

class Practical(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have tried using `subject_id` instead of `forloop.counter`, but still same problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `{% if practical.subject == subject %}`  this will make only one item to show per subject. It is kind hard to understand what you want...

Comment: @MarcusRenno The main purpose of that if-statement is to display the practical from the database only if 'practical.subject' equals to the subject as taken in the outer loop. This actually displays all the practicals in the specified subject (not just a single item). The only problem occurs when I use the anchortags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I address the main solution, I'd like to point out that the two `forloop.counter`'s you are using are counters for two different forloops. the anchortag on top where you define with `href="#c{{forloop.counter}}"` is using the forloop counter for `% for subject in subjects %}`.

But the div that I assume you want to be displayed (defined with `id="c{{forloop.counter}}"` is using the forloop counter for `{% for practical in practicals %}`.

This will cause the numbers to be off.

Now, the real issue is in the structure of your html. That is... you are only displaying one element when you click on the anchortag. the id it targets is a unique id that is unique to one single element. Therefor, only that element will be displayed. There are two alternatives you could do...

1. wrap the list of element `div`s in another `div`. If you do this, you will have to target the wrapper `div` instead of the elements.

e.g.

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
<div class="panel-heading">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#list__practical" 
                       aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="list__practical">
                       {{ subject }}</a>
<div>
<div id="list__practical">
    {% for practical in practicals %}
    {# Your element html here #}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The key is the id on the one wrapping the practical forloop and the references to it instead of a dynamic id.

2. use classes instead of ids

e.g.

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
<div class="panel-heading">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=".list-element" 
                       aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="???">
                       {{ subject }}</a>
<div>
{% for practical in practicals %}
    <div class="list-element panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel"">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="{% url 'practicals:detail' practical.id %}">{{ practical }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Please note that I've never used aria-* stuff before whatever that is so I'm not sure how the changing of the ids or classes will effect that.

Comment: Thanks. The piece of you wrote was not directly helpful, but the concept behind it was found to me helpful. Thanks a ton.